# Mongoid 'or' and 'in' - querying multiple arrays

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a document in Mongo with two array fields:

```
field   :app_usernames,     type:  Array 
field   :email_addresses,   type:  Array
```

I'd like to create a function which take an array of usernames and an array of email addresses to search collection. The kicker is that I want it to return documents which have *any* of the values passed in the arrays:

```
def find_people(usernames_to_search, emails_to_search)...
```

So given a document with field values:

```
app_usernames = ['test1','test2','test3']
email_addresses = ['test1@test.com','test2@test.com']
```

I want the function to find it when any of those values are searched, via the array parameters. It should return this document in the following cases:

```
find_people nil,['test1@test.com']
find_people ['test3'],['test1@test.com']
find_people ['oldusername'],['test1@test.com']
```

The last one seems to be causing me trouble.

Thus far I've tried

```
.or(:app_usernames.in usernames_to_search, :email_addresses.in emails_to_search)
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `or` method is meant to be called with a list of individual conditions so that it can turn this:

```
x.or(condition1, condition2)
```

into a MongoDB query like:

```
$or: [ condition1, condition2 ]
```

When you say:

```
.or(:app_usernames.in => usernames_to_search, :email_addresses.in => emails_to_search)
```

How many arguments are you passing to `or`? The answer is one. You're actually saying this:

```
.or({ :app_usernames.in => usernames_to_search, :email_addresses.in => emails_to_search })
```

You need to add the braces yourself so Ruby doesn't collapse the arguments into one Hash:

```
.or(
  { :app_usernames.in   => usernames_to_search },
  { :email_addresses.in => emails_to_search    }
)
```

Or something like this:

```
args = [ ]
args.push(:app_usernames.in => usernames_to_search) if(usernames_to_search.present?)
args.push(:email_addresses.in => emails_to_search)  if(emails_to_search.present?)
query = query.or(*args) if(args.present?)
```